# How to determine the status of a Git branch/what do the SourceTree icons mean?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm using SourceTree - can someone tell me what the icons mean.  I need to know a couple of things:
1) if a branch has been merged back into master
2) if a local branch has been pushed back to the remote origin.

Thanks very much
Tim

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of that tool you use.

Comment: There is none.  I have read the FAQ's and searched through the user forum and SO with no useful info on what the branching icons mean.

Comment: Well, then ask their support. It is a commercial product. They should know. Sorry, don't get me wrong, I am not trying to push you away or something. It is just that only few people use such utilities, since `git` itself works and is usable perfectly well by itself. So the chances for an answer are not that high...

Comment: Aha.. git branch --no-merged remotes/origin/master

Comment: oh.. still no closer.  I cannot see when any of the merges were done.  fail.  resorting to deleting all branches and starting again.. thankfully I have a backup of the source code. From what I've read sounds like many people suffer from the git-complex.